# Ansible filter stdout_lines cut or split

Tags: python, split, ansible, jinja2

I have a variable which contains a few lines and I want to find of a line having this value and after split based a delimiter and take only the first value of that specific line.

```
Task:1
   - debug:
       var: blabla.stdout_lines

Output
  blabla.stdout_lines:
  - 1 test1 aaa
  - 2 test0 bbb
  - 3 test444 ccc


Task:2
   - name: test
     debug:
       msg: "{{ blabla.stdout | select('search', 'test1') | list }}"
Output
  msg:
  -  1 test1 aaa
```

I would like to have a split so it takes just the value "1" directly in the task2. I tried to do a textsplit and cut into it but seems it wasn't working. 
I am trying to add another Jinja filter into the Task2.

Comment: Your question is very opaque; do you mean that instead of `"search", "test1"` you want to only match on the leading numbers? Are you aware of [`regex_search()`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters)?

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel I want my output in task 2 to give me the "1" as the output instead of the full line. . The first select('search' ) looks for the line that contains the line I am looking for but after I want to do a split on the line so the output is "1" , Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Thank you Matthew for the help ! Regex_search() was something I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Managed to used regex_search() as Matthew suggested

```
   - name: Extract valuevariables

     set_fact:

        webapps_not: "{{ blabla.stdout | regex_search('.+?(?=no)') }}"


   - name: Show value

     debug: var=blabla_not
```